# PyDev can't see _pydevd_bundle in debug mode for Google App Engine

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

Eclipse Neon 4.6.0, PyDev 5.1.2, OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, GAE SDK 1.9.40

The project I am working on runs locally and on appspot.com, I'm trying to move to Eclipse from Pycharm to see if Eclipse works better for me. I have the PyDev plugin installed. The project works fine while running in debug mode too.

When the debugger pauses at a break point I get this warning on the console:

```
/Users/[my_user_id]/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py:85: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '_pydevd_bundle' not found while handling absolute import
```

While I have the debugger paused at any break point at all and I enter any valid or invalid command at the Python prompt I get the expect response from Python followed by this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[my_user_ID]/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_save_locals.py", line 35, in save_locals
ImportError: No module named _pydevd_bundle
```

My assumption is that the path to the _pydevd_bundle is somehow a problem but, the normal fixes are not getting it.

That path is:

```
/Users/[my_user_ID]/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256/pysrc
```

I have checked that in Finder.

So far I have tried the following:

- Reinstalled Eclipse & PyDev from alternate mirror sites in case there
  was some corruption
- Forced the path to the _pydevd_bundle into the system path.
- At Preferences >> PyDev >> Interpreters >> Python Interpreter:

  - Added the path above to the PYTHONPATH list
  - Added all the modules under that `/pysrc` directory to the Forced
    Builtins list
  - I've also tried going down to the module directory itself which
    should not be needed since all the module directories have an
    `__init__.py` file.
- Before the reinstall I even tried commenting out the offending import
  statement in the pydevd_save_locals.py file.

The only thing I have not tried is blowing away my entire Python install and starting from scratch with everything attached to that. Just more work with a 50/50 shot at a fix.

Since the debugger appears to work okay this might be more of an annoyance than anything else. But, it's potentially hiding other errors however. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I upgraded the GAE SDK to 1.9.40, reinstalled Eclipse, and reinstalled PyDev, no joy.

Comment: Temporary work around - In pydev_xml.py I've commented out lines 71 - 88 and in pydev_save_locals.py I've commented out lined 35 - 38 and 50 - 61. I may have inserted a line in there so the row counts might be a little off. These are PyDev files. If you run into this same issue and have to do this to get by make sure you back these files up or be prepared to reinstall PyDev which is actually pretty easy. Time permitting I'd like to trace through this to see if it's PyDev or GAE or some interaction between the two. Thx. -j